# Why does my JWT expiresIn value change between sending it from the server and receiving it on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I set my token expiry date on the server and `console.log` out the value to check:
[image: server expiry date]

However, when I check the value on my React front-end, I get this value:

[image: front-end expiry date]

I don't alter the expiry date in any way but the value is changed dramatically between sending it and receiving it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Server code

```
const d = new Date();
        console.log(
          'current date: ',
          moment(d.getTime()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        );
        /*const calculatedExpiresIn =
          d.getTime() +
          60 * 60 * 1000 -
          (d.getTime() - d.getMilliseconds()) / 1000;*/
        const calculatedExpiresIn = d.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000;
        console.log(
          'calculatedExpiresIn: ',
          moment(calculatedExpiresIn).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        );
        console.log('calculatedExpiresIn: ', calculatedExpiresIn);

        const iat = d.getTime();
        const user = ok([
          {
            id: res[0].id,
            token: jwt.sign(
              {
                id: res[0].id,
                email: res[0].email,
                firstName: res[0].firstName,
                surname: res[0].surname,
                role: res[0].role,
                iat: iat,
              },
              config.secret,
              {
                expiresIn: calculatedExpiresIn,
              }
            ),
          },
        ]);
```

Front-end code

```
validateSession() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('unikey');
    const d = new Date();

    if (token && token !== undefined) {
      let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      /*console.log('decodedToken: ', decodedToken);
      console.log(
        'decodedToken iat date: ',
        moment(decodedToken.iat).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
      );*/
      console.log(
        'decodedToken expiry date: ',
        moment(decodedToken.exp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
      );
      console.log(
        'current date: ',
        moment(d.getTime()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
      );
      console.log('decodedToken expiry date: ', decodedToken.exp);
      console.log('current date: ', d.getTime());
      console.log('Time difference: ', decodedToken.exp - d.getTime());

      if (d > decodedToken.exp) {
        console.log('Time is up...');
        this.terminateSession();
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      // There is no token so session is automatically invalid
      this.terminateSession();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NDQsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0Iiwic3VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWdlbnQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTg1NTYyOTE3MzAsImV4cGlyeSI6MTYxODU1OTg5MTczMCwiZXhwIjozMjM3MTE2MTgzNDYwfQ.nUrUFzyyP9POBTklc8ISXamJIz8D9vaUOIdS81_F9FY
```

Comment: I've worked around it by simply adding an extra field in the jwt body with my own expiry date which I reference but I'd still love to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoded payload is:

```
{
...
  "iat": 1618556291730,
  "expiry": 1618559891730,
  "exp": 3237116183460
}
```

There are two things wrong:

1. The format of the timestamps is wrong, because it's supposed to be in seconds  (10 digit number) instead of milliseconds (13 digits) (see [NumericDate in RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2)).
2. The the expiration time is (aside from the factor 1000) twice as high as expected.

The reason for that is a wrong calculation of the `expiresIn` parameter in you call to `jwt.sign`. The [parameter](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim) is supposed to be a timesspan, e.g. `{ expiresIn: 60 * 60 }` or `{ expiresIn: "1h" }` for one hour, instead of a timestamp.
The `sign` function will then add the timespan from the parameter to the current time to calculate the correct `exp`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware of the timestamp format but it was the expiration time which was really confusing me. The reason I put the date and time in `exp` was because I kept getting the wrong expiry date no matter what I did. I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one though as it answers my question. Thank you again very much.